# print pdf with java

Tags: java, pdf, printing

I have tried to print pdf with this code:

```
package imprimir;

import java.io.*;
import java.awt.print.*;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob.*;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat.*;

public class Imprimir {

    static public void main(String[] args) {
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        PageFormat pf = job.defaultPage();
        Paper paper = new Paper();
        paper.setSize(612.0, 832.0);
        double margin = 10;
        paper.setImageableArea(margin, margin, paper.getWidth() - margin, paper.getHeight() - margin);
        pf.setPaper(paper);
        pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
        job.setPrintable(new ObjetoDeImpresion(), pf);
        job.setJobName("funciona?");
        try {
            job.print();
        } catch (PrinterException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}


package imprimir;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.print.*;

public class ObjetoDeImpresion implements Printable {

    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat f, int pageIndex) {
        if (pageIndex == 0) {
            g.drawString("Hola ivan", 100, 200);
            return PAGE_EXISTS;
        } else {
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }
    }
}
```

and also from other different ways there on the internet, but with all the ways I've tried, when I print the document, print odd numbers and letters, like this:

```
% PDF ||1.6
endobobj <</linerrized 1/L 20597/O 40/E 14115/N 1/T ............
xref
37 34
0000000013 00000 n
0000000013 00000 n
0000000013 00000 n
0000000013 00000 n
0000000013 00000 n
0000000013 00000 n
0000000013 00000 n
0000000013 00000 n
0000000013 00000 n
0000000013 00000 n
0000000013 00000 n
0000000013 00000 n
0000000013 00000 n
0000000013 00000 n
0000000013 00000 n
...
..
..
trailer
<</Size......
```

Someone can help me achieve print my document?

Comment: Have you tried using iText: http://itextpdf.com/itext.php

Comment: Where do you get the described output?

Answer (score 4):

I think PDFBox from Apache better suit your need (http://pdfbox.apache.org/).

Here is how it can fit inside your code:

```
static public void main(String[] args) {
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    PageFormat pf = job.defaultPage();
    Paper paper = new Paper();
    paper.setSize(612.0, 832.0);
    double margin = 10;
    paper.setImageableArea(margin, margin, paper.getWidth() - margin, paper.getHeight() - margin);
    pf.setPaper(paper);
    pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);

    // PDFBox
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load("yourfile.pdf");
    job.setPageable(new PDPageable(document, job));

    job.setJobName("funciona?");
    try {
        job.print();
    } catch (PrinterException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

You can find more info about this if you look at the source of org.apache.pdfbox.PrintPDF.

Comment: Hello, I did what you told me. Download the PDFBOx.jar and copy your code ... Even so the printer will not print what should be printed.

The file I have is "test.pdf" is a sheet containing some text and an image. But what is printed on the sheet are just numbers like it is printing in hexadecimal

Comment: You might want to open an issue in PDFBox JIRA. Or send me the PDF file, if it isn't confidential.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use iTEXT

[iText Web Link](http://itextpdf.com/)

**Tutorials**

[Tutorial # 01](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaPDF/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

We have tried PDFBox too, also PDFView and IText, but what worked best for us was using the systems ghostscript to render the PDF into an image - otherwise in our PDF with a couple of images and form fields, things would get rendered not perfectly.

First write your pdf to an temporary file, then call gs:

```
        String command;
    if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("windows"))
    {
        command = "gswin32";
    }
    else
    {
        command = "gs";
    }

    String absolutePath = pngFile.getAbsolutePath();
    command = command + " -q -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE="
                + color.name()
                + " -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dFirstPage="
                + pageNo + " -dLastPage=" + pageNo + " -r" + dpi
                + " -sOutputFile=" + absolutePath + " "
                + pdfFile.getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println(command);
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    boolean success = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1200; i++) //wait for completion
    {
        try
        {
            p.exitValue();
            success = true;
            break;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.trace(e.getMessage());
        }
        Thread.currentThread();
        Thread.sleep(200);
    }
    if (!success)
    {
        p.destroy();
    }
```